# Jquery Issues with IE8 and Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Having an issue with the following code on IE8 and some android versions.  The variable "method" is always unset throwing the alert even when the object it refers to is checked.  This works in most every other browser except IE8 and possibly IE9, as well as some android OS's (haven't nailed down exactly which ones).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#choose_shipper').click(function(){
var method = $('#fedex_method:checked').val();
 if (!method){
  alert('Please select a shipping option');
}else{
      DO SOMETHING ELSE HERE
    }
    });
 });
```

EDIT
Simple answer, stupid habit...  I was using multiple instances of the same id...  Older browsers don't like that and treat all duplicate instances like they do not exist.  SO!  Changing "fedex_method" from an ID to a CLASS solved all the problems!  My BAD!

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a single checkbox, try this instead

```
var method = $("#fedex_method").prop("checked");
```

To evaluate multiple checkboxes, something like

```
var method = $("#fedex_method:checked").length;
```

Or (since you should not have multiple checkboxes with the same id):

```
var method = $("input:checkbox[name=fedex_method]:checked").length;
```

Per the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is true of all boolean attributes.
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property:
>
> ```
> if ( elem.checked )
> if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
> if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
> ```

Comment: Good to keep in mind, however my problem was far simpler.  I have edited my question.